# How to determine the round of a game given it's state number?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I've made a game where it's possible to mark a total of 15 categories as either used or unused, and have a game score that's anything in the range of 0 and 39 (both inclusive, and ignoring that marking a category leads to a certain minimum score). The total number of game states is therefore 2^<sup>15</sup> *40. Marking a category is associated with a round in the game, so after marking your 4<sup>th</sup> category (any of the currently unmarked ones are available) you're in the 4<sup>th</sup> round. Determining the number of states in any round ***i*** is done using some combinatorics:

$g_{i}=\frac{15!}{(15-i)!(i!)}$

If I summarize all states in each round in sequential order, then it must be possible to say that the ***j***'th state is in round ***r***. Is there a formula to determine, given a state number, which round the state belongs to?

Comment: use factoring or modulo, it should hold round k iff $0 = j \mod 2^k$ or $0 = j \mod k$ it is hard to understand the state and round from the question excatly but in any case they should be exact multiples of one the other

Comment: the deternination of $j$ is lacking, is this just an index on the state at round $k$ or is it related in another way? In the first case it is not possible to relate $j$ to $k$ since multiple $k$'s have same $j$'s  In the other case an exact factoring or counting may work

Answer (score 0):

No, this is a difficult problem, basically you need to evaluate the break-off points for each round (the last number of state pertaining to each round). Notice the break of point of round $n$ is $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{15}{k}$. This number is really hard to compute and has no closed form.

I here give you a table of the break-off points:

$$
\begin{matrix}
1&16\\
2&121\\
3&576\\
4&1941\\
5&4944\\
6&9949\\
7&16384\\
8&22819\\
9&27824\\
10&30827\\
11&32192\\
12&32647\\
13&32752\\
14&32767\\
15&32678\\
 \end{matrix}$$